# Do Euclidean spaces prove more statements than Euclidean geometry?

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry

Is there a statement in the language of Euclidean geometry (as defined in [Hilbert's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms)) that

- is undecidable by Euclidean geometry
- is provable in the Euclidean space of dimension 3

I'm trying to get an opinion about whether geometrical proofs using coordinates introduce a bias, or decisions that are absent in Euclidean geometry.

Comment: What do you mean by "provable in the Euclidean space"? If you mean provable from the usual facts about real numbers using coordinates, then how about the classical ones: (a) every angle is three times some angle, (b) every cube has half the volume of some other cube, (c) every circle has the same area as some square.

Comment: Isn't Tarskian geometry a complete first order theory ? If I remember correctly, it is, and if he's not wrong, Henning's comment shows that you perhaps need to specify what you mean by "Euclidean geometry" (as it was defined by Euclid, you can't really consider it a mathematical theory in modern terms, and so understanding what it can't prove can be quite difficult)

Comment: Indeed, I clarified my question with a link to Hilbert's axioms. I believe that by the second axiom of continuity, one can prove that a line is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. So all statements mentionned by Henning Makholm seem provable by Hilbert's axioms.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the language of Euclidean geometry"?  Hilbert's axioms are not first-order, and they assume a background set theory.  So, are all set-theoretic statements fair game?

Comment: My point is that referring to "the language of Euclidean geometry" makes it sound like you have some precise (probably first-order) language in mind, but this doesn't make much sense if you are talking about Hilbert's axioms.

Comment: And if we say Tarski instead of Hilbert, I don't think that (b) and (c) -- that is, doubling the cube and squaring the circle -- can even be _expressed_ in the language of Tarski's geometry. Which makes it somewhat dubious whether that language ought to be elevated to "the language of Euclidean geometry".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By any reasonable interpretation, the answer is no.  Hilbert's axioms are categorical, meaning that you can prove that any two structures which satisfy them are isomorphic.  In particular, you can prove any structure satisfying Hilbert's axioms is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ (with its usual geometric structure).  So any statement you can prove about $\mathbb{R}^3$ (and which involves only the structure described by Hilbert's axioms) is true of any other model of Hilbert's axioms.

(Note that in the context of Hilbert's axioms, it's not very meaningful to talk about "the language of Euclidean geometry" or statements that are "decidable in Euclidean geometry".  Hilbert's axioms are not a self-contained proof system.  Rather, they are an axiomatizaton of a structure which is intended to be interpreted within an ambient set theory.  So the language you can use when talking about Euclidean geometry via Hilbert's axioms is really your entire background set theory, or at least some big fragment of it.  A proof that uses fantastically complicated auxiliary set-theoretic constructions to reason about an arbitrary model of Hilbert's axioms is a perfectly good Euclidean geometry proof, if you define Euclidean geometry by Hilbert's axioms.)

---

If you instead use a first-order axiomatization like Tarski's axioms, the answer depends on what you mean by "the language of Euclidean geometry".  The most obvious meaning is the first-order language of Tarski's axioms, in which case the answer is no: Tarski's axioms generate a complete first-order theory, so the first-order statements you can prove from them are exactly the first-order statements which are true of any single model (e.g., $\mathbb{R}^3$).  But if you allow higher-order statements, then the answer is yes.  For instance, $\mathbb{R}^3$ is uncountable, but there are models of Tarski's axioms which are countable.  Or for something more classical, Archimedes' axiom is true in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but is not true in arbitrary models of Tarski's axioms.

Comment: Thanks. Can you update your answer adding the Tarski case as logical foundation ? Or any other axioms you think would give more sense to my question ? I can accept this answer already and raise another question for the other cases if you prefer.