# How much of Euclid's number theory can be reproduced in Hilbert's axiomatization of geometry?

Tags: geometry, logic, arithmetic, axiomatic-geometry

In book VII of the *Elements*, Euclid develops some fundamental results from number theory. How much of this, if any, can be reproduced in Hilbert's axiomatization? It seems to me that the answer is close to nothing, since Hilbert's formalization can't even state the basic arithmetical concepts. Is this correct? On what basis do we today differentiate arithmetic from geometry, that Euclid did not have (or respect)?

Comment: You are right we can do next to nothing. We can't express the notion of a quantity being made up of multiples of some units.

Comment: You can do arithmetic with line segments within Hilbert's axiomatisation. Addition and subtraction is easy. Multiplication and division takes a little bit of constructing, and require that you establish some base line segment to be the unit length.

Comment: If it contains all of plane geometry, it should allow at least addition, subtraction, multiplication by an integer, division by an integer, calculation of $bc/a$ (reduces to multiplication if $a$ is a predefined unit length), calculation of $b/(ac)$ (reduces to division for unit $a$), calculation of geometric mean $\sqrt{ab}$ (reduces to square root for unit $a$), because all that can be done with compass and ruler.

Comment: Hilbert's axioms are not a self-contained logical system, so your question doesn't really make sense.  If you allow higher-order reasoning (which you should, since Hilbert's axioms are higher-order), then you can certainly formulate all of number theory in the context of a model of Hilbert's axioms.  The story would be very different if instead you asked about a first-order variant of Hilbert's axioms.  See my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425773/do-euclidean-spaces-prove-more-statements-than-euclidean-geometry/2425796#2425796 for related discussion.

Comment: In any case, your final question seems to be very deeply misguided.  There is no sharp distinction between "arithmetic" and "geometry".  Equating "geometry" with one particular axiomatization of Euclidean geometry and making some kind of philosophical point based on this is totally ridiculous.

Comment: It think that trying to make a distinction between arithmetic and geometry isn't entirely ridiculous from a philosophical perspective. I certainly wouldn't equate geometry with any one axiomatization, but it's still clear a) that most geometrial theories are much weaker than theories of arithmetic, since we can prove completeness theorems about them, b) that arithmetic has a crucial role to play in metamathematical considerations, given the arithmetical character of logic (formalisms being inductively defined structures). So asking about a distinction between them isn't prima facie ridiculous.

Comment: Induction might be the sticking point; I don't quite know how to formalize the idea of "only use geometry and the number theory that arises from it, not the number theory you already know", but any way of doing it would probably leave out induction.

Comment: You can see the post [Is there a formalization of the link between geometry and analytical geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183391/is-there-a-formalization-of-the-link-between-geometry-and-analytical-geometry) for a brief overview of the *Algebra of segments* developed in **Ch.15** of Hilbert's *Foundations of Geometry* (1899).